# Game returns Command Executed

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I have looked all over for this. What is happening is that when I do my command It doesnt display the code I am needing, It is like the /ping bukkit command.
https://prnt.sc/tluruk

Its my understanding that this is because I need to fix something with my return statements but I dont get it at all. (if someone could explain that would be very nice)

Heres my code:

```
package me.leSs_cOws.support;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;


public class Support extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
        saveConfig();
        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("leSs_cOws' Support Enabled");
        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("Please Rate this plugin 5 Stars on spigotmc if you liked!");
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
        saveConfig();
        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("leSs_cOws' Support Disabled");
        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("Please Rate this plugin 5 Stars on spigotmc if you liked!");
        
    }
    
    public boolean oncommands(Player p, Command cmd, String label, CommandSender sender, String[] args, Bukkit b) {
        
        
        
        if (sender instanceof Player) {
            String line1 = getConfig().getString("line1");
            String line2 = getConfig().getString("line2");
            String line3 = getConfig().getString("line3");
            
            
            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("support")) {
                
                sender.sendMessage(line1);
                sender.sendMessage(line2);
                sender.sendMessage(line3);
                
                return true;
            }
            
            return true;
        }
        else if (sender instanceof Player) {
            String discord = getConfig().getString("discord");
            
            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(discord)); {
                
                sender.sendMessage(discord);
                return true;
            }
        }
        else {
            sender.sendMessage("You cant send that command here");
            return true;
        }   
    }
}
```

I have no errors and I export with nothing wrong. Thanks :)
https://prnt.sc/tluu06

Here is my yml files

Config- https://prnt.sc/tluuu6

Plugin- https://prnt.sc/tluv4p

These also have no errors

Comment: Your else if block will never execute.  If (sender instanceof Player) then it will take the first block.  else (which means that is not true) then you test the same thing again.  Since you're in the else clause, that test will fail by definition.  Perhaps you meant to have an else (with not test) on the inner if statement?

Comment: yea, but no. my elseif statement does run and the /discord block does show up in minecraft as something you can tab to.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your else if command block will never get executed because it has the same conditions as the if block before.

I don't think that your problem is directly related to your boolean return values. You can find more information about it in [this tutorial](https://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Plugin_Tutorial) I quoted. I think that Bukkit behaves as if it received *false* since it gets no value.

> The onCommand method must always return a boolean value - either true
> or false. If the value returned is true then you won't see any
> noticeable events. However if it returns false then the plugin will
> revert to your plugin files' 'usage: property' and display a message
> to the user showing them how to use the command as specified in the
> plugin.yml file.

*from https://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Plugin_Tutorial*

I think the mistake, that you've made, is that you haven't **correctly set the function name**. Your function is named "oncommands" but it should be called "onCommand" and have the @Override annotation like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("basic")) { // If the player typed /basic then do the following, note: If you only registered this executor for one command, you don't need this
        // doSomething
        return true;
    } //If this has happened the function will return true. 
        // If this hasn't happened the value of false will be returned.
    return false; 
}
```

This is important because it isn't your own, new function, but overrides the existing functions of the extendet "JavaPlugin" class.

It is recommended and more organized to create a new class for every command. Your class must implement the interface CommandExecutor.

This tutorial explains it well: https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/create-a-simple-command/